# Get product categories ids from order items in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms, product-variations

I have a couple of code snippets to get product categories, they are working but they all miss out the category for variable products.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
$items = $order->get_items();
$categories = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $product_categories = $product->get_category_ids();
    //...
}
```

This snippet has the same issue. (It is using a hook from an invoice plugin but I don't think that is relevant)

```
add_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_item_meta', 'wpo_wcpdf_show_product_categories', 10, 3 );
function wpo_wcpdf_show_product_categories ( $template_type, $item, $order ) {
    wc_get_product_category_list( $item['product']->get_id() )
    //...
}
```

Products will only ever have one category if that matters.

I tried this as suggested somewhere but still returns false?

```
$the_product = wc_get_product( $item['product']->get_id() );
$variable_categories = wc_get_product_category_list( $the_product->get_id() );
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get product categories ids from order items, use the following instead:

```
$category_ids = array();

foreach($order->get_items() as $item) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );

    $categories = array_merge( $category_ids, $product->get_category_ids() );
    //...
}
```

So in your hooked function:

```
add_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_item_meta', 'wpo_wcpdf_show_product_categories', 10, 3 );
function wpo_wcpdf_show_product_categories ( $template_type, $item, $order ) {
    wc_get_product_category_list( $item->product_get_id() )
    //...
}
```

This will work.

> For product variations, you always need to get the parent variable product, which you always get using the `WC_Order_Item_Product` `get_product_id()` method.